# XCode: Accidently delete "Link Binary with Library" option from Build phases

Tags: xcode

I accidentally deleted "Link Binary with Library" option from my project's "Build Phases". Now I am unable to see this option in my project's target-> Build Phases. (As a result my all Frameworks and libs are removed) My project is showing errors. Can anybody guide me as to how to recover it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a menu item you can use to add build phases.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Abizem. It solve my problem. Thomas Thanx u too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the Git-Repository when creating the project? If you did, right click on your project file and go to “Source Control” then “Discard changes…”.

If this is not the case and ⌘+z does not help, do you have some kind of time-machine backup?

Comment: I managed to git restore my file at ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj